# Solving a cubic function for second and third degree polynomials?

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, polynomial-math

I have a program I'm writing in which the user has the option to choose between solving a cubic function for either second or third degree polynomials. Once choosing, the program applies a number of formulas, including: solving the 2nd degree discriminant, the quadratic formula, the formula for polynomials of the second degree, Cardano's analogous method of third degree polynomials, and the standard cubic formula (basically, the first four formulas on this [page](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/)).

Here's my code:

```
import math

def deg3():
    print("This is a third degree polynomial calculator.")
    print("Please enter four numbers.")
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    c = int(input())
    d = int(input())

# Apply Cardano's compressed method to find x root, broken up into different variables.
p = (-1 * b)/(3 * a)
q = p ** 3 + (b * c - (3 * a * d))/ (6 * (a ** 2)) 
r = c / (3 * a)

x = (q + (q**2 + (r - p**2)**3) **1/2) **1/3 + (q + (q**2 + (r - p**2)**3) **1/2) **1/3 + p
print("The root is:", x)

# Applies final cubic formula, and returns.
total = (a * x**3) + (b * x**2) + (c * x) + d
total = round(total, 3)
return total

# If discr > 0, then the equation has three distinct real roots.
# If discr = 0, then the equation has a multiple root and all its roots are real.
# If discr < 0, then the equation has one real root and
# two nonreal complex conjugate roots.
```

Now it easily returns a total. The computation is correct, but I'm still trying to wrap my brain around the analogous formula. What is the discriminant part of the equation? How do I find potential roots, like I do with the quadratic formula? Probably a no-brainer question, but I want to understand the process better.

Comment: What is the question? I'm afraid that's not clear at all.

Comment: Edited for clarity. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user1739537: The code in this question could be made much simpler while still explaining your problem- all you need is the `cubic` function (none of the others) and a single line calling it (like `cubic(1, 2, 3, 4)`). Making your example *minimal* will get answers much faster.

Comment: the way you compute the solution might lead to catastrophic cancellation. Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are *many* differences between your cubic function and the equation on the site you link to. Among the most notable:

1. Your order of operations is off: a line like:

   ```
   big = (-1 *( b**3 / 27 * a**3) + (b * c / 6 * a**2) - (d / 2 * a))
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   big = (-1 *( b**3 / (27 * a**3)) + (b * c / (6 * a**2)) - (d / (2 * a)))
   ```

   otherwise, a term like `27 * a**3` won't end up in the denominator- it will instead be seen as 27 in the denominator and `a**3` afterwards.
2. You never include a cube root, even though there are two in the equation you link to.
3. You do `x * 2 - small`, but the two items added together in the equation are not identical- one has a plus sign where the other has a minus.

However, even if you fix all the issues with the function, you will still get a math domain error when trying to solve many cubic equations. Note this paragraph from your link:

> But if we apply Cardano's formula to this example, we use a=1, b=0, c=-15, d=-4, and we find that we need to take the square root of -109 in the resulting computation. Ultimately, the square roots of negative numbers would cancel out later in the computation, but that computation can't be understood by a calculus student without additional discussion of complex numbers.

Solving cubic equations requires dealing with complex numbers (though only temporarily- as noted, they'll cancel out), so you can't use `math.sqrt` to solve it. You might be interested in the [cmath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) package.

Comment: Thank you David! This was very helpful. Fortunately, I only really need cases involving real numbers, but I'll take a look at the cmath package anyways. I'll post my updated code if I have any problems. Thanks again.

Comment: I used a compressed cubic equation, i.e. Cardano's method. Edited my question for further investigation.

Comment: by the way, what do you mean having both a plus and minus sign? I don't see it. If one were to use the Cardano formula, what number would determine the number of roots (real only)? Honestly, I'm confused about how it works.

Comment: @user1739537: Look after the first end parentheses (after `d/(2a)`) within each of the cube roots in [this image](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/cubic.gif) from that page- one of them is plus, the other minus. And importantly, even if you only want answers with real numbers you *still* have to use complex numbers along the way! Try using the equation to solve the cubic with `a=1, b=0, c=-15, d=-4` as given in the example above. It has a real solution but you can't get to it without using complex numbers briefly.

Comment: Ah! Solved. Thank you, David.